# Autocomplete on Partial Matches in the Middle of a filename in Terminal (dash/bash)

Tags: 12.04, command-line, unity-dash

I have a bunch of directories:

```
20130118-Cars_Directory
20130118-Bikes_Directory
20130218-Planes_Directory
20130228-Scooters_Directory
```

Is there any way to change directories in the manner of typing a partial match in the middle of the command.

Ideally, something in the style of `cd *Bikes*<TAB>`, and have dash autocomplete the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, by coincidence, it turns out that `cd *Bikes*<RETURN>` works without any changes to the system.

I am just a little stunned that it didn't require quotes around `*Bikes*`.

Answer (score 7):

You can do that by creating an alias for cd and defining a bash completion as your will. See [Bach Completion manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html).

Here is a step by step guide. I will use "scd" for our new command, but you can use "cd" as well.

**1) Editing .bashrc file**

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

**2) Creating the alias**
*Paste this in the final of the ".bashrc" file:*

```
# Alias for making a "Super cd"

alias scd="cd"

_scd_completion() {
    mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <(ls -d */ | grep "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}")
}
complete -F _scd_completion scd
```

Save and close.

**3) Open a new terminal**
*Or run:* `source ~/.bashrc`

**4) How to use**

Just call the command followed by part of the name of the directory you want to go.

`scd Bikes<TAB>`

Done. Enjoy!

Comment: Perfect!  And what a good solution ... this speeds up my navigation in Terminal a lot.  Thank you for tanking the time to code the bash completion.

Comment: Best regards ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the tool called [z](https://github.com/rupa/z), it allows what you need, plus it creates a global database of your cd's weighted by frequency and allows you to jump to frequently visited place instantly.

If you have visited the Bikes directory, you can later type

```
z Bikes
```

and you will jump there

Comment: Can you elaborate how to use `z` for what the user had asked for?

Answer (score 1):

[The answer from desuga](https://askubuntu.com/a/276463/953371) works, but it is case sensitive.

If you do not want it to be case sensitive, the `~/.bashrc` file should be:

```
# Alias for making a "Super cd"

alias scd="cd"

_scd_completion() {
    mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <(ls -d */ | grep -i "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}")
}
complete -F _scd_completion scd
```